# Zip files and directories starting from a target directory

Tags: python, directory, zip

My script's working directory looks like this:

```
my_script.py
random/
      |_ system/
                |_ folder/
                |         |_ fileA
                |_ fileB
                |_ fileC
```

I want to zip `system` and all it's sub-directories and files such that the final result should look like this:

```
output.zip
          |_system/
                   |_ folder/
                   |        |_ fileA
                   |_ fileB
                   |_ fileC
```

The problem with my solution (below) is that it is including the directory `random` in the output zip. In other words, the resulting zip's tree starts at the location of `my_script.py`.

```
target = 'random/system'

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip', mode='w')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target):
    zip_file.write(root)
    for file in files:
        zip_file.write(root + '/' + file)

zip_file.close()
```

This is the (flawed) output of my code:

```
output.zip
          |_random/
                   |_system/
                            |_ folder/
                            |        |_ fileA
                            |_ fileB
                            |_ fileC
```

**Without moving any of the directories/files, how can I get the desired output? How can I exclude the directories between my script and the target directory?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple matter of changing your working directory. When you invoke the script, make sure there is an `os.chdir()` statement in there. Then, when you do the `os.walk()`, you are passing in `system` instead of passing in `random/system`. The following should work:

```
import os
import zipfile

os.chdir('random')
target = 'system'

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('../output.zip', mode='w')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target):
    zip_file.write(root)
    for file in files:
        zip_file.write(root + '/' + file)

zip_file.close()
```

As a matter of style, you should perform the file I/O inside a `with` like so:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('../output.zip', mode='w') as zip_file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target):
        zip_file.write(root)
        for file in files:
            zip_file.write(root + '/' + file)
```